# Cannot init webdriver in jenkins server after upgrade selenium to v4.11.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, webdriver, guava

After upgrade to selenium v4.11.0 I cannot init webdriver in jenkins server, it throws out with message `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` but I'm still able to run on local with the same code, same JDK, any advise for this case?

```
Message: 'org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumOptions
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.addArguments(java.lang.String[])'
    Stacktrace:
    `at com.paltech.driver.browser.DesktopChromeDriver.<init>(DesktopChromeDriver.java:67)
    at com.paltech.driver.DriverManager.initSeleniumDriver(DriverManager.java:132)
    at com.paltech.driver.DriverManager.createWebDriver(DriverManager.java:115)
    at baseTest.BaseCaseTest.createDriver(BaseCaseTest.java:279)
    at baseTest.BaseCaseTest.loginAgent(BaseCaseTest.java:136)
    at baseTest.BaseCaseTest.beforeMethod(BaseCaseTest.java:121)
    at     java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104`)
    `at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:589)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1385)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1354)
```

Dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

I am running with JDK 20 and chromedriver 115
I have tried to upgrade guava to latest version 32.1.2 but it still not working